# How would you reply to 'よかったら'?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, word-usage

I always assumed you would reply to a phrase containing よかったら with はい or いい but is that correct? If so, which sounds more natural?

For example, if someone were to say "よかったら、英語を教えて欲しい" to you, how would you reply?

Answer (score 1):

Because of 良かったら basically being the conditional of 良い, I guess いい(です)よ  or something like it would be the most used response. It’s also the sentence I tend to hear the most in response to that.

Japanese people tend to answer a question with the same verb/adjective the question was asked with.

> 昨日 映画館に行きましたか。
> (Did you go to the movie theater yesterday?)
>   - はい、行きました。
> (Yes, I went.)

Answer (score 0):

If you think of it in terms of English as well, the answer provides itself. This is a case of subject agreement, if anything else, that is somewhat similar in both languages. Consider this request and response pair:

> A: よかったら、英語を教えて欲しいです。
>   (If it is alright with you, I'd like you to teach me English.)
>   B: はい。
>   (Yes.)

It is direct, and maybe a little curt, to just respond with a blunt はい. It's understandable, but it's preferable to agree with the request politely, by addressing the request in a similar tone. Since what is in question is whether it is alright or not, the response is formed around that. See below:

> A: よかったら、英語を教えて欲しいです。
>   (If it's alright with you, I'd like you to teach me English.)
>   B: [はい、]　いいですよ。
>   ([Yes,] It's alright.)